# retrieve job details by job id using redux and axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a jobs list. I have to retrieve a job details by passing 'jobid' as a paramater using axios. i have created action and reducer for that and connect to that my component. api is getting called but in jobid it is showing undefined. I think it is route problem. Please suggest me where to defined that and how to get the details.

My api is like(ex: 'http://localhost:3000/app/jobs/87938'). Here jobid is 87938. There are multiple job with different job id in my job list. Problem is how to define the jobid and passing to the api to retrieve the details of job

action code:

```
export const retrieveLocations = (jobId) => (dispatch) => {
  axios.get(retrieveUrl+'/jobs/'+jobId).then(res => {
      dispatch({
          type: RETRIEVE_LOCATION,
          payload: res.data.job.basicDetails
      });
  });
};
```

reducer code:

```
case 'RETRIEVE_LOCATION':
            return{
                ...state,
                conLocations:action.payload
            }
```

component code:

```
class ConfiguredLocation extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
        this.clearall = this.clearall.bind(this);
    }


    handleRemove(mruCode){
       this.props.removeLocation(mruCode)
    }

    clearall (){
      this.props.removeAllLocation()
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
        let currJobId = this.props.match.params.jobId;
        let prevJobId = prevProps.match.params.jobId;
        if(currJobId!==prevJobId){
            this.props.retrieveLocations(jobId);
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        let {jobId} = this.props.match.params;
        this.props.retrieveLocations(jobId);
    }

    render(){
        const _labels = store.getLabels();
        const {conLocations} = this.props;
        return(
            <div className="col-padding">
              <div className="pos-div"><h3>Configured Location</h3><button className="allLargeBtn" onClick={()=>{this.clearall()}}>Remove all location</button></div><hr/>
               <table className="table">
                    <tbody>
                        {conLocations.map((loct,index)=><tr key={index}>
                           <td><h5>{loct.mruCode} - {_labels[loct.division]} - {loct.country}</h5></td>
                           <td className="text-right"><img alt="DeleteIcon" onClick={()=>this.handleRemove(loct.mruCode)}className="deleteIconStyle" src="img/delete_large_active.png" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        )}
                    </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return {
        conLocations: state.locationRed.conLocations
    };
  };

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
      return{
          removeLocation: (mruCode)=>{dispatch(removeLocation(mruCode))},
          removeAllLocation: () =>{dispatch(removeAllLocation())},
          retrieveLocations:(jobId) =>{dispatch(retrieveLocations(jobId))}
      };
  };


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(ConfiguredLocation));
```

router code(appnavigator - i am not able to define job id here. Please suggest me on this)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Security, ImplicitCallback, SecureRoute } from '@okta/okta-react';
import history from '../history';
import store from '../stores/store';
import ConfiguredLocation from '../components/location/ConfiguredLocation';
class AppNavigator extends React.Component {

    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );
        this.state = {
            loading: true
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(() => {
            self.setState({ loading: false });
        }, 1000);
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return (
                <div className="fix"><i className="fa fa-2x fa-circle fa-spin"></i>
                    <div>Loading</div>
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            return (                    
                <Router history={history}>
                    <Security issuer={Something..}
                        client_id={something...}
                        redirect_uri={window.location.origin + '/app/callback'}
                        scope={['profile', 'openid']}>
                        <Route path='/callback' component={ImplicitCallback} />
                        <AppFrame />
                    </Security>
                 <Route exact path= '/jobs/:jobId' component={ConfiguredLocation}
                </Router>
            );
        }
    }
};
```

store code:(where appnavigator called)

```
<Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
            <AppNavigator />
        </Provider>
```

Everything is working fine. If i call the api without parameter. it is working fine. So i am not able to route the parameter properly. Please help me on this.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gni]l.png

Comment: I can't see your `/app/jobs` in your router file!

Comment: @MohammadRezaKhedri thanks for your response. I am not sure that i am doing correct or not. I have edited my question. If possible will you please suggest me the possible way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

All your code is correct after editing. When you want to generate dynamic route, like `jobId` in `/app/jobs/87938` route, first you should write this route in router file like this:

```
<Route exact path="/app/jobs/:jobId" component={ConfiguredLocation}/>
```

after that, When open `http://localhost:3000/app/jobs/87938` route your `jobId` is `87938` and you can get it in your componentDidMount lifecycle:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const {jobId} = this.props.match.params;
    this.props.retrieveLocations(jobId);
}
```

**Demo:**

[image: Edit i2zt0]

Comment: still it is getting undefined. In console, it's looking like this : xhr.js:178 GET http://localhost:3000/api/jobs/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: demo added in my response. if you set any id in route, jobId show in dom.

Comment: i have added the imported files in my appnavigator component. Is there any issue? Other code is correct it seems. i am not getting any other error. Only undefined error

Comment: if you want help you in your code, please put your code in `codesandbox`.